# PHP transform an array with a simple function

Tags: php, arrays

Would there be a simple native PHP function that would transform this array:

```
Array
(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 1
        [module_libelle] => Qualités esthétiques
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 2
        [module_libelle] => Qualités pragmatiques
    )
...
 )
```

in this array:

```
Array
(
[1] => Qualités esthétiques
[2] => Qualités pragmatiques
...
)
```

without function like foreach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you also want to keep the `id` as the array key in the result array, you might use [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

```
$result = array();
array_walk($array, function ($value) use (&$result) {
    $result[$value->id] = $value->module_libelle;
});

print_r($result);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/S8NMQ)

Or you might use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$array = array_reduce($array, function($carry, $item) {
    $carry[$item->id] = $item->module_libelle;
    return $carry;
});

print_r($array);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/7OouT)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `array_map`

```
$arr = //your array

$result = array_map(function($o){
    return $o->module_libelle; //Return the property of the object
}, $arr);

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will return as:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Qualités esthétiques
    [1] => Qualités pragmatiques
)
```

Doc: a[rray_map()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)